# What makes this integral so hard to solve?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

The integral $$ F(x) = \int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^4+10x^2-96x-71}} \, dx ,$$ has a closed-form expression, namely, $$F(x) = -\frac{1}{8} \ln\left((x^6 + 15x^4-80x^3 + 27x^2-528x + 781)\sqrt{x^4 + 10x^2-96x - 71} - (x^8 + 20x^6 -128 x^5 + 54x^4-1408x^3 + 3124x^2 + 10001)\right) \\ +C. $$

It seems that most, if not all, computer integrators such as Mathematica fail to find its antiderivative. What makes this integral so hard to solve, and how do you begin solving it?

Comment: $\sqrt{...}$ of fourth order polynomial = nasty (however it is known that integrals of your type, with an additional x in the numerator can in principle always reduced to elementary functions)

Comment: For sure, realizing that $$x^4+10x^2-96x-71=(x^2-11)^2 - 12(x+4)^2$$ is pretty useful in tackling such integral by integration by parts and substitutions.

Comment: Mathematic does get this in closed form, as a truly vicious expression involving elliptic functions.  The problem is, Mathematica is not all that good at clever simplifications when it comes to square roots and tric functions, much less elliptic functions.

Comment: If you factor the expression under the radical as$ (x-\sqrt{3}+2\sqrt{2(\sqrt{3}-1)}) (x-\sqrt{3}-2\sqrt{2(\sqrt{3}-1)})(x+\sqrt{3}+2i\sqrt{2(\sqrt{3}+1)})(x+\sqrt{3}-2i\sqrt{2(\sqrt{3}+1)})$ the problem becomes easier. But I can't even get this expression to show up in a comment...

Comment: This integral is awsome (awful?).  Where did you get it from?